# Irrlitch Projects Not Loading In Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, irrlicht

Actually I Just Completed with My entire C++ Courses.

I Am Into game development Stuff, As A Beginner  a Using Irrlitch game Engine,
And visual Studio Code Community 2019.

I have tried so hard to build all examples in projects but I wasn't able to do,
I have followed This Steps To Build up All Examples In Irrlitch Folder From website,
Step 1: Download Irrlicht
Step 2: Unzip Irrlicht
Step 3: Go to folder irrlicht-1.8.4/examples
Step 4: Double click the file BuildAllExamples_vc12.sln
Step 5: In Visual Studio, in Solution Explorer, you will see all the projects. Right click on the project names Irrlicht and select properties
Step 6: Under Configuration Properties->General, change the Platform Toolset to Visual Studio 2019 and click Ok
Step 7: Right click on the HelloWorld project, select properties and change the Platform Toolset in the same manner to Visual Studio 2019
Step 8: Once again right click on the HelloWorld project and select "Set as Startup Project"
Step 9: Hit play

problem is my vs community is showing project not loaded,
and showing this error when I try to reload the project.

```
C:\Users\Alaica 07\Downloads\irr;icth\irrlicht-1.8.4\irrlicht-1.8.4\source\Irrlicht\Irrlicht12.0.vcxproj : error  : The name "icth\irrlicht-1.8.4\irrlicht-1.8.4\examples\15.LoadIrrFile\LoadIrrFile_vc12.vcxproj">Debug|Win32</ProjectConfiguration>
<ProjectConfiguration Project " contains an invalid character "\".
```

Comment: Now that I can see the error message the problem appears to be your path for the project `irr;icth` is somehow confusing the IDE. My advice for programming is to keep the path of your projects simple. Avoid spaces and other symbols in the path.

Comment: no sir, actually irr;icth is just the folder name which i mistyped earlier

Comment: ***contains an invalid character "\".*** should be something you can look at yourself. The project file is a text file that is xml.